# How to subscript a single quotation mark?

Tags: punctuation, subscripts

I can do:

```
\emph{f$_i$$_j$}
```

to get *f<sub>ij</sub>*

But how do I get *f<sub>ij'</sub>*?

I've tried:

```
\emph{f$_i$$_j$$_'$}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean `\emph{f$_{ij'}$}`?

Comment: Or simply $f_{ij'}$?

Comment: yeah cool, didn't know nested brackets work.

Comment: the font used by `\emph` is entirely different to the math italic font used by `$` and sets its content in text mode.

Comment: Why using `\emph`? It is preferable to just use `$f_{ij'}$`.

Comment: Do you want `$\mathrm{f}_{ij'}$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm putting this as an answer so that the question does not remain unanswered.)

As was pointed out in the comments, you might want to use `$f_{ij'}$` instead.